What is the genealogy of Mahishasura?
Vaishnavas worship lord Narasimhadeva as the destroyer of demons. Narasimhadeva killed Hiranyakashipu, the lord of the Daityas who conquered heaven and earth. He was the son of Kashyapa and his wife Diti. Kashyapa was the son of Sage Marichi, who was the manasaputra of lord Brahma (ref: Vishnu Purana, Book I).
Shaktas worship the Goddess Chandika as the destroyer of demons. Chandika killed Mahishasura, who conquered heaven and earth. However, I do not know anything about Mahishasura. Who was his father? Nothing is mentioned about the genealogy of Mahishasura in SriSriChandi (Devi Mahatmya or Durga Saptashati). Can anybody tell who were the parents of Mahishasura? Please give references from the scriptures.

Mahiṣāsura(महिषासुर) was the son of the asura Rambha and a she-buffalo named Mahisi (Vamana Purana, Adhyaya 17). He was ultimately killed by the goddess Durga with her trishula (trident) after which she gained the epithet Mahishasuramardini (Slayer of Mahiṣāsura). Mahiṣāsura had a son named Gajasura (Siva Purana, Rudra Samhita, Yuddha Khanda, Chapter 57).
Mahiṣāsura's story is told in the major texts of the Shakta traditions known as the Devi Mahatmya [Ch-81 to 93, 700 verses arranged into 13 chapters] which is part of Markandeya Purana [137 Chapters]. The story of Mahishasura is told in the chapter where Markandeya is narrating the story of the birth of Sāvarṇimanu(सावर्णिमनु). As per the Markandeya Purana, the story of Mahishasura was narrated in the second Manvantara by Maharishi Medha to the king Suratha.
The Navaratri (Nine Nights) festival praises highly this battle between Mahiṣāsura and Durga, culminating in Vijayadashami, a celebration of his ultimate defeat. This story of the "triumph of good over evil" carries profound symbolism in Shaktism.

Asura, rambha, she buffalo mahishi, gajashura are not mentioned in devi mahatmya. Wrong information.

Yes, it was wrong info. My apologies.
(1) Refer [Vamana Purana, ch-1.6 section-1] for Rambha and Mahisi (she-buffalo) and birth of Mahiṣāsura.
(2) Refer [Shiva Purana: Section 2.5, Rudra-saṃhitā (5), Yuddha-khaṇḍa: Ch-57] the conversation between Rishi Sanatkumāra  and Vyasa Muni about Gajāsura son of Mahiṣāsura.

Thank you so much for the reference.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay ,Fyi, please refer the conversation between King Janamejaya and Vyāsa Muni about birth of Mahiṣāsura, son of Rambha and Mahisi (she-buffalo) in Devi Bhāgavata Purāna [Skanda-5, Chapter-2]. Hope this additional reference will be found useful to you. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57191.html

Devi Bhagavat Purana, Book V, Chapter 2

17-26. Vyāsa said — O king! Rambha and Karambha were the two sons of Danu; these two Dānavas were far famed in this world for their pre-eminence. O king! They had no issues; hence, desirous of issues, they went to the sacred banks of the Indus (Pañcha Nada) and there performed severe asceticism for long years.


Indra assumed the form of a crocodile and caught hold of the legs of the wicked Karambha and killed him. Hearing of the death of his brother, Rambha got very much enraged and wishing to offer his own head as an oblation to the Fire;


Fire gave him knowledge, desisted him from this act and spoke thus — You are stupid; why have you desired to cut off your own head; killing one's ownself is a great sin; and there is no means of deliverance from this sin. Why are you then ready to execute it? Do not seek your death now; what end will that serve you? Rather ask boons from me; thus you will get your welfare.


27-31. Vyāsa said — O king! Hearing thus the sweet words of Fire, Rambha quitted the hold of his hairs and said — O Lord of the Devas! If thou art pleased, grant my desired boon that a son be born unto me, who will destroy the forces of my enemy and who will conquer the three worlds. And that son be invincible in every way by the Devas, Dānavas and men, very powerful, assuming forms at will, and respected by all. The Fire said — O highly Fortunate! You will get your son, as you desire; therefore desist now from your attempting suicide. O highly fortunate Rambha! With any female of whichever species, you will co-habit, you will get a son, more powerful than you; there is no doubt in this.


32-50. Vyāsa said — O king! Hearing thus the sweet words of the Fire as desired, Rambha, the chief of the Dānavas, went, surrounded by Yaksas, to a beautiful place, adorned with picturesque sceneries; when one lovely she-buffalo, who was very maddened with passion, fell to the sight of Rambha. And he desired to have sexual intercourse with her, in preference to other women.


The she-buffalo, seeing her husband laid in the funeral pyre, expressed her desire to enter also into that fire.


When the she-buffalo died, the powerful Mahisa rose from his mother's womb from the midst of the funeral pyre;

Reference -
Devi Bhagavat Purana
